# How to handle input change in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making a very simple react application that has the basic details as inputs.

I am having these form values in context.

**context.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const FormContext = React.createContext();

export function FormProvider({ children }) {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    basicDetails: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      address: {
        city: "city",
        zip: "zip"
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={[formValue, setFormValue]}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In basic details component, I am trying to render the form like,

**basicdetails.js**

The below code is **working fine**

```
    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name: </label>
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      id="firstName"
      name="firstName"
      value={basicDetails.firstName}
      onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
    />
```

The below code is **not working**

```
    <label htmlFor="lastName">City: </label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="city"
      name="city"
      value={basicDetails.address.city}
      onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
    />
```

**Reason:**

The second given input lies under nested object ie.., `basicDetails.address.city`.

And I am giving the name attribute value as `city` only.

```
   basicDetails: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      address: {
        city: "city",
        zip: "zip"
      }
    }
```

But the `handleInputChange` covers only parent level changes.

```
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setValue((prev) => {
      const basicDetails = { ...prev.basicDetails, [name]: value };
      return { ...prev, basicDetails };
    });
  };
```

**Requirement:**

Please kindly help me to update the form that has nested object as well.. `basicdetails.address.city` .

[image: Edit React Functional Component (forked)]

**Note:**

Now I am having city and zip but later it may extend and more number of fields will be added to it.. So I cannot hardcode the condition check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this approach to check whether any property exist in the json or it should be stored in the `address`:

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value: val } = event.target;
    console.log("name", name, value);
    // if (name === city)
    // const updateName =
    setValue((prev) => {
      const basicDetails = {
        ...prev.basicDetails,
        ...(value.basicDetails[name] !== undefined
          ? { [name]: val }
          : { address: { ...value.basicDetails.address, [name]: val } })
      };
      return { ...prev, basicDetails };
    });
  };
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-5nwuy?file=/src/components/basicdetails.js:370-626)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But I am in the need to handle this dynamically.. Now I am having ```city``` and ```zip``` but later it may extend and more number of fields will be added to it.. So I cannot hardcode it..

Comment: Adding to that in your solution, ```zip``` has been moved to parent level but it needs to be inside ```address``` only.. For now I am having two inputs in parent level and two inputs in nested level (under address) ..

Comment: now it's handled dynamically. Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: What does this line mean? ```const { name, value: val } = event.target;``` ? I am getting error in my real app that ```'value' is not defined``` ..

Comment: as you had a variable called value already, I renamed the `event.target.value` to `event.target.val` in order to prevent confusion.

Comment: Also what would happen if I have another three nested object inside ```basicDetails``` similar like ```address``` ?

Comment: then you should handle it by passing another parameter to the `handleInputChange` function to clarify whether it belongs to the `address` or that other nested object. Then store it in the right place.

Comment: can you pls mark it as the correct answer if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for the reason you said: it is a nested object. One solution would be to check if the input is a city or a zip input and if so, change the nested `basicDetails.address` object instead of the `basicDetails` object directly:

```js
const basicDetails = Object.keys(prev.basicDetails.address).includes(name)
  ? {
    ...prev.basicDetails,
    address: { ...prev.basicDetails.address, [name]: value }
  }
  : { ...prev.basicDetails, [name]: value };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But I am in the need to handle this dynamically.. Now I am having ```city``` and ```zip``` but later it may extend and more number of fields will be added to it.. So I cannot hardcode it..

Comment: `Object.keys(prev.basicDetails.address)` should work then. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    <label htmlFor="lastName">City: </label>
<input
  type="text"
  id="city"
  name="city"
  value={basicDetails.address.city}
  onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event,(parentPropName = "address")}
/>
```

then in your handleInputChange  :

```
 const handleInputChange = (event,parentPropName ) => {
const { name, value } = event.target;
  if(parentPropName ){
    setValue((prev) => {
  const basicDetails = { ...prev.basicDetails,[ parentPropName ]: 
      ...prev.basicDetails[parentPropName ],
       [name] : value
      };
  return { ...prev, basicDetails };
  });
  }
    else {
setValue((prev) => {
  const basicDetails = { ...prev.basicDetails, [name]: value };
  return { ...prev, basicDetails };
});
};

 }
```

for other fields just remove parentPropName and in if condition it will be undefined and going to be false