# Object clone in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-context

I am making a simple react application which has some basic inputs like `first name`, `last name` etc..,

The state of the inputs are handled in context api like,

**context.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const FormContext = React.createContext();

export function FormProvider({ children }) {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    basicDetails: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      address: {
        city: "",
        zip: ""
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={[formValue, setFormValue]}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In basic details component fetching the context like,

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useContext(FormContext);
  const { basicDetails } = value;
```

Here to make a copy of initial value of context, I have tried using spread operator like,

```
  const initialValue = { ...value };
```

And in `handleSubmit` function tried to get the initially copied value (i.e..,) `initialValue` but this is logging the values of latest changes.

**Working example:**

[image: Edit React Functional Component (forked)]

**Requirement**:

On click of the form submission, I am in the need to reset the form values with initial context data.

To achieve the resetting of values to initial data only I have tried spread operator `{ ...value }` but I think I am wrong with the approach.

Even `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))` doen't work in this case..

Kindly anyone help me to achieve of setting the form value to initial context on submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer here seems sufficient. You could also save the initial field values in a React ref (`const initialValue = React.useRef(value);`) and access later as `initialValue.current`.

In reality you want your context to have more control over the context state. I suggest creating a `reset` function to include in the context that children can consume.

context.js

Factor out the initial state definition, provide a default context value, and pass the state and callbacks to the context value.

```
const initialFormState = {
  basicDetails: {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    address: {
      city: "",
      zip: "123"
    }
  }
};

export const FormContext = React.createContext({
  formValue: initialFormState,
  setFormValue: () => {},
  reset: () => {}
});

export function FormProvider({ children }) {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState(initialFormState);

  const reset = () => setFormValue(initialFormState);

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider
      value={{ value: formValue, setValue: setFormValue, reset }}
    >
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

basicDetails.js

Consume and destructure the context value. Change the submit button to be of `type="submit"` so you can submit the form, and call `reset` in the submit handler to reset the form state.

```
const BasicDetails = () => {
  const {value, setValue, reset} = React.useContext(FormContext);
  const { basicDetails } = value;

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value: val } = event.target;
    setValue((prev) => {
      const basicDetails = {
        ...prev.basicDetails,
        ...(value.basicDetails[name] !== undefined
          ? { [name]: val }
          : { address: { ...value.basicDetails.address, [name]: val } })
      };
      return { ...prev, basicDetails };
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do what you need with the current form values
    console.log("Values", value);

    // Finally reset the form
    e.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Basic Details </h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} onReset={reset}>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          value={basicDetails.firstName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="lastName"
          name="lastName"
          value={basicDetails.lastName}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="lastName">City: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="city"
          name="city"
          value={basicDetails.address.city}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Zip: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="lastName"
          name="zip"
          value={basicDetails.address.zip}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit object-clone-in-react]

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro.. I have one doubt related to this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67265409/13270726 .. Is there a way to change this line of code ```{ address: { ...value.basicDetails.address, [name]: val } })``` in ```handleInputChange``` function because some times I would have more objects like ```address``` so is there a way to handle without hard coding of data?

Comment: @Undefined Ideally you want your form data to be flat. Your state is not though, so the "mapping" from nested to flattened (or vice-versa) *necessarily* occurs in the `setValue` function. You could abstract this into a utility that can parse an object path though, something that can parse `name="basicDetails.address.city"` into the nested state you need to update. See [lodash object set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) for what I'm describing.

Comment: Okay bro thanks for your comment, will go through it..

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to keep the initialValue always as the first time value, you need to do it like

```
const initialValue = useMemo(() => value, []);
```

as your code, the function runs whenever the value changes, so the initialValue changes every time when the value changes